# What's wrong with my SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, select

I'm using this code to get the last number in a column where date of column is today date:

```
cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\bysys.mdb")
rs.Open("Select max(snum) From tblbill where idate = #" & Format(Today.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy") & "# ", cn, 1, 2)

If IsDBNull(Rs.Fields(0).Value) Then
    TextBox6.Text = 1
Else
    TextBox6.Text = Rs.Fields(0).Value + 1
End If
```

Sometimes it works correctly, but sometimes, it always return 1..

Comment: Are you certain that the `max(snum)` for today isn't, in fact, a `NULL` ?

Comment: Does it only work on days before the 13th? Would suggest using yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: We can't comment without knowing what the data looks like.

Comment: not null friend!, there is a record in a database

Comment: `Format(Today.Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")`

Comment: THANKS Mike Miller & HansUP, it's done

Answer (score 3):

When you submit a value which can represent a valid date in *mm/dd/yyyy* format, Access will interpret it as such.  You could deliberately format it as *mm/dd/yyyy* instead of *dd/mm/yyyy*.  But many of us prefer *yyyy/mm/dd* because Access always interprets that format correctly and we humans needn't be bothered about possible confusion over whether the date is *dd/mm/yyyy* or *mm/dd/yyyy* format.

```
"Select max(snum) From tblbill where idate = #" & Format(Today.Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "# "
```

However the db engine supports a function, `Date()`, which your query can use to refer to the current date without bothering about any formatting.  So this alternative seems simplest to me ...

```
"Select max(snum) From tblbill where idate = Date()"
```